# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void

Tags: java, android, banco-de-dados, sqlite

Boa noite, não estou conseguindo resolver o problema, diz que tem um objeto não referenciado (null object reference), mas não tem o que inicializar o seguinte código:

```
public void deletar(int id)
    {
        conn.delete("RESULTADO", "_id = ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(id)});
    }
```

Ele diz que é aqui!
O erro: *Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void project.henry.count.domain.repoResult.deletar(int)' on a null object reference*.

O código que utilizam esse método:

```
Button btnApagar;
...
    btnApagar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnApagar);
    btnApagar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            try{
                repoResultado.deletar(dados.getId());
            } catch (Exception ex){
                mensagem("ERRO: " + ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O que está nulo é o seu objeto `repoResultado`. Você não deve ter inicializado ele. Por isso dá o erro de referência nula quando tenta chamar o método `deletar` dessa classe.

Comment: Deu certo agora, realmente ele não estava sendo instanciado. Obrigado!